# Fulltext accents

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, diacritics

How I can do to make me these two queries return the same results?

`móvil` vs. `movil`

**Table rows:**

INSERT [Palabras] ([Id], [texto]) VALUES (1, N'Movil iphone 6')
INSERT [Palabras] ([Id], [texto]) VALUES (2, N'Móvil iphone 6')
INSERT [Palabras] ([Id], [texto]) VALUES (3, N'Moviles iphone 6')
INSERT [Palabras] ([Id], [texto]) VALUES (4, N'Móviles iphone 6')

Returns 4 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Palabras
WHERE CONTAINS(*, N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "móvil", 3082, NULL, 0)');
```

Returns 2 rows:
Only returns: *Movil iphone 6* , *Móvil iphone 6*

```
SELECT *
FROM Palabras
WHERE CONTAINS(*, N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "movil", 3082, NULL, 0)')
```

**View the tokenization result of a word breaker, thesaurus, and stoplist combination:**

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "móvil")', 3082, NULL, 0);
```

Display_term: `moviles`, `movil`

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser(N'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "movil")', 3082, NULL, 0);
```

Display_term: `movil`

Comment: Can you provide samples of what your 1st query matches? Does the word móvil exist in the table or only other forms of the word like móviles?

Comment: The table is only four rows

Answer (score 1):

Change the full text catalog's `ACCENT_SENSITIVITY` to OFF and rebuild.

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [MyFullTextCatalog] REBUILD WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
```

Comment: I checked this before and it did not work.
SELECT FULLTEXTCATALOGPROPERTY('GLCatalog', 'accentsensitivity');
**Result: 0**

Comment: @Arbems Have you rebuilt the catalog? Also what language is the full text index using?

Comment: If I have rebuilt. Language 3082 Spanish

Comment: And Database collaction Modern_Spanish_CI_AI